# "paths must precede expression" error when trying to find all jpg files in the current directory

Tags: find

while running find command to find all the jpg files in the current directory as

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *.jpg
```

i am getting the error as :

```
 find: paths must precede expression: pic1 (1).jpg
 Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-Dhelp|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

i am not able to figure out what is wrong with that .

Comment: If you have a .jpg file in the current directory then your shell will expand your wildcard to be a list of the jpg files. Put your pattern in quotes to prevent this:   "*.jpg"

Comment: @Nerdling: Why don't you make your comment an answer (which it is)? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr** Always quote globs in find: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg"` (notice the `"` characters surrounding `*`).

In your case, the shell is interpreting `*.jpg` (note the `*` character) and trying to match file names within the current directory that end in `.jpg`.  There is a file named `pic1 (1).jpg` so that file name replaces `*.jpg`.  The command the system is given by the shell becomes

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'pic1 (1).jpg'
```

To see in depth, try tracing the original command using `strace`.  What is actually executed is:

```
touch foo.jpg bar.jpg
strace find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *.jpg 2>&1 | grep jpg
execve("/usr/bin/find", ["find", ".", "-maxdepth", "1", "-type", "f", "-name", "bar.jpg", "foo.jpg"], [/* 62 vars */]) = 0
...
```

Comment: strace is a great tool, but definitely an overkill for somebody who doesn't understand shell expansion. It's much simpler to step back in the shell history and just prepend the command with "echo".

Comment: `Always` is, as always :) , too often. `find proj*` -type f -name foobar` will search in every directory which matches ./proj* for example; perfectly valid and reasonable.